# discord.py question about message formatting codeblocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello I have been wondering about few days cause I'm not that deep into python but how would one create this?

[image]

basically let's say you have a lits of 500 or more usernames and you want the output to be like that and of course there's a 2000 char limit and you'd need to do multiple separate codeblocks. My only concern is how?

Comment: You would probably add them line by line until you pass the limit and then put everything else into another message. However, you can trip ratelimits really quickly (and it would look ugly but that isn't very large of a concern) so you can also upload the entire thing as a file, which will be automatically displayed in desktop, and it will also do syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `discord.py` this is done with the help of the [`ext.command.Paginator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=paginator#paginator) class.

Basically, it divides your text into several "pages" so you can send them in separate messages accounting for the Discord's message symbols limit.

Example of a code would be:

````py
# somewhere in your command
paginator = commands.Paginator(prefix='```python')
paginator.add_line('some line')
paginator.add_line('some other line')

for page in paginator.pages:
    await ctx.send(page)
````